# Laravel add csrf check for link

Tags: wordpress, laravel, csrf

I'm implementing post **DELETE** action in laravel using a hyperlink as wordpress does:
`http://mysite/wp-admin/post.php?post=568&action=trash&_wpnonce=ec36bea1fd`

 last part of link has a `wpnonce` that is `csrf` in laravel . but laravel csrf middleware doesn't check csrf for `get` requestes  . is it possible to force app to check for `_token`?
and is it necessary ? if it isnt so why wordpress does a check for it?

Comment: That's not necessary for `GET/HEAD` requests.

Comment: Using get method to delete something is a bad idea.

Comment: are you calling this using ajax? or calling from within wordpress using curl. any of the cases the csrf token is there on the cookie. you can take it and send it on the header of the request as X-CSRF-Token

Comment: @astroanu I'm using neither ajax nor wordpress . as i said i'm trying to delete a post using a link tag like `<a class="btn btn-danger" href="//site/admin/destroy?id=96">Delete</a>` i may append `csrf_token()` to link but  no verifying would be done at server side. this is my issue

Comment: passing a csrf token on the url is not a good idea. How about implementing an api for the Laravel app and then calling that from wp?

Answer (score 0):

Just don't do it, use a DELETE or POST request.

Comment: but i have to use it ! there is a table listing all posts and each post should has a delete button and a checkbox to be able to be selected for bulk action just like wordpress, therefor if using a form for delete action then it would be inside another form that is bulk action form and it is not a valid html

Comment: "what about AJAX?" Are you really suggesting he should use XML?

Answer (score 0):

This is asked several years ago, but this might be useful for others.
When you are using a link you should use a javascript onclick method to add a _token to the form and submit it so user would see it as a link.

Another way that worked for me was this:

make a link like the following:

```
 <a href="/panel/news/delete/{{$news->id}}/{{CSRF_TOKEN()}}" >
```

then check it like this:

```
   public function delete(Request $request,$id,$token)
    {
        if(csrf_token() != $token)
         return throw new \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
       // do the deletion
     }
```